# How to use Google Custom Search for image search in objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-custom-search, google-image-search

can any one please tell me how I can use google custom search in my iphone application to search images only. I tried it but it asks for 'cse' or 'cx' parameter. Please help.

Comment: Any one taking first step towards it this will be the right place to start http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/656600

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Google Custom Search API** lets you develop websites and programs to retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically.

With this API, you can use RESTful requests to get either **web search** or **image search** results in JSON or Atom format.

See the available documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

See [this one](https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/jsondevguide) too

**Note:**

**cx:** The identifier of the custom search engine.

Visit the [**Google Custom Search page**](http://www.google.com/cse/) to create a custom search engine for testing purposes. Select the sites that you would like to include in the search and configure the other options.

Click on "**control panel**" and note your **Search engine unique ID**. This is the **cx parameter** used by the API.

See the [full documentation here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/getting_started)

Example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures

<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=cars&callback=hndlr">
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your response. I am using the method mentioned at second link that you mentioned here. But it gives me a limited number of hits only as it is deprecated one. I also read the custom search api but can't understand the 'cx' parameter that how to use it in the api. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: @Ramshad hey for iPhone this api is now available? if yes then how to implement it?

Comment: @Ramshad  it's nice but is is depricated one. any other option available for ios app

Comment: @Rushi: The only way is, use the Custom Search API, which now supports image search. https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

Comment: but it need to be implemented on server  thats problem.

Answer (score 3):

By the way You can use my poor library ([YCustomSearchEngine](https://github.com/yanlobkarev/YCustomSearchEngine))

Comment: Thanks.. Although I didn't use you library but it is a good one.. :)