# Google Image search integration in Iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, iphone-5

I am working on google image search. I found so many url's for this. But problem is in all url's, they are passing the value as string to parameter.

[How to use Google Custom Search for image search in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319115/how-to-use-google-custom-search-for-image-search-in-objective-c)

this is one of the questions. In developer sites also they provided string parameter only like  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=apple

Here "apple" is value for parameter 'q and getting results for apple.

But i want to send image as a value to the parameter and getting results of that particular image.

Plz help me. I googled a lot. i found above like url's only. I didn't find my requirement.

Thanks in advance.
Mahesh

Answer (score 2):

There's another question that seems fairly similar, [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10141800/google-search-by-image-api)

If I understood one of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10141902/2611971).  Google has deprecated their imageSearch api.  The answer also provides a link to a new api, [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), but that seems to only have the option to send text and receive images as search results.  There doesn't appear to be a reverse image search available.  I did however come across a third-party api by Tineye that seems to have a mobile api and things ready to go. Check it out [HERE!](http://www.tineye.com)

Note: I have not tried, nor do I have any affiliations with Tineye, I just came across it and thought I'd offer a suggestion.

#### Update

After some serious searching, I have solution no. 1 based on the answer: [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13859357/2611971)

If you upload your image to a server or backend of some sort, and generate a URL, you can submit it this way:

```
NSString * yourImageURL = //...//;
NSString * searchURL = @"https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url="

NSString * completeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", searchURL, yourImageURL];
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 

http://www.emergingedtech.com/2012/03/google-image-search-you-can-use-a-picture-as-a-search-parameter/

here no sample is provided.

we have google search app for ios, is it possible to integrate that google search app into my app?

Comment: See update.  It's definitely possible, it's just not a supported API so there's potential for problems.