# iOS and Google api

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api

I am developing an app that will make a google search from a text input entered by the user.

My question is, do i need to use the google api or is it possible to just make a URL fetch with the user text, like so:

user entered "Skype"

```
    NSURLSessionConfiguration * config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession * session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

NSURLRequest * request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/search?q=%@"], userInput];
NSURLSessionDataTask *data = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *theDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", theDic);
}];
[data resume];
```

and in the returned data i will get all the results from the search "Skype".
Is it possible?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're definitely going to want to use the actual API. You'll need to sign up and get an API key. Using the regular web search URL will give you back a webpage as a result, which is probably not want you want for interacting with in an iOS app.

[Here is a link to the API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) and [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list) is a link to this specific API call.

Your query will look something like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=<YOUR API KEY>&q=<YOUR QUERY>&cx=<CUSTOM SEARCH ENGINE ID>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15319115/how-to-use-google-custom-search-for-image-search-in-objective-c) is an answer with more info about the Custom Search API.